# How to turn off explorer loopback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, explorer, loopback

i used

```
{
  "loopback-component-explorer": {
    "mountPath": false
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "loopback-component-explorer": null
}
```

still cannot turn off explorer loopback

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
"loopback-component-explorer": {
    "mountPath": "/explorer"
}
```

and the eplorer will not work any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{
  "loopback-component-explorer": {
    "mountPath": false,
    "generateOperationScopedModels": true
  }
}
```